# How to define div style property as a function in ejs?

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm trying to create lecture blocks, which height is determined by their start and end times. I'm doing this by substracting start time from end time, then dividing it to 15 minute intervals and multiplying them by 50px. I was wondering would it be possible for me to define div height style property as a function, which calculates the height of each and every block?

```
**// EJS Code**

<div id="mit_1-1" style="float: left">
  <% for(n=0; n<times[0].lectures.monday.length; n++){ %>
    <div style="width: 150px; margin-right: 25px; background-color: red;">
      <h3><%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].title %></h3>
      <h3><%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].classroom %></h3>
      <h3><%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].start %></h3>
      <h3><%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].end %></h3>
    </div>
  <% } %>

**Script to calculate the block height**

<script>
  function getLectureBlockHeight(el){
    var result = ((new Date(el[0].end) - new Date(el[0].start))/1000)/60; // get lecture's length in minutes
    result = (result / 15) * 50; // get amount of 15 minutes intervals and multiply by 50
    return result;
  }
</script>

**// This is how I was hoping to make it work**

<div id="mit_1-1" style="float: left">
  <% for(n=0; n<times[0].lectures.monday.length; n++){ %>
    <div style="height: getLectureBlockHeight(times[0].lectures.monday[n]) + px; width: 150px; margin-right: 25px; background-color: red;">
      <h3><%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].title %></h3>
      <h3><%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].classroom %></h3>
      <h3><%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].start %></h3>
      <h3><%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].end %></h3>
    </div>
  <% } %>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you provided?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @CalebGoodman i'm not getting a specific error message, but the block height stays the same on all of them, which is auto and based on fixed 150px width

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is trying to assign a height of `getLectureBlockHeight(times[0].lectures.monday[n]) + px;`
which doesn't make sense and is probably throwing an error in the browser console.

If you can calculate the height you want on your server, I would recommend saving that value to a variable then using the following code:

```
<div style="height:'<%= div_height %>px'; width: 150px; margin-right: 25px; background-color: red;">
```

If you *need* to calculate the height with client-side JS, then you will have to insert the value using jQuery.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> //you always need this for jQuery to work!  Remember to put this before using any jQuery code

<script>
  function getLectureBlockHeight(el){
    var result = ((new Date(el[0].end) - new Date(el[0].start))/1000)/60;
    result = (result / 15) * 50;
    return result;
  }
</script>

 <% for(n=0; n<times[0].lectures.monday.length; n++){ %>
 <div id="<%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].someUniqueId %>" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 25px; background-color: red;">
  <h3><%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].title %></h3>
  <h3><%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].classroom %></h3>
  <h3><%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].start %></h3>
  <h3><%= times[0].lectures.monday[n].end %></h3>
</div>

<script>
  $('#<%=times[0].lectures.monday[n].someUniqueId%>').css(
      {width:getLectureBlockHeight(<%= times[0].lectures.monday[n] %>).toString() + 'px'}
  )
</script>
<% } %>
```

Note that you will have to have a unique ID for each object in `times`.  If you can't get this working let me know what errors you are getting.  Hope this helps!